# Six functor formalism for quasi-coherent $D$-modules

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, d-modules

Let $X$ be a smooth scheme over a field $k$ and let $\mathsf{D}_{\text{qc}}(\mathcal{D}_X)$ be the full subcategory of $\mathsf{D}(\mathcal{D}_X\mathsf{-Mod})$ composed of the complexes of $\mathcal{D}_X$-modules with quasi-coherent cohomology.

If $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism between such schemes, we have natural functors
$$f_*:\mathsf{D}_{\text{qc}}(\mathcal{D}_X)\leftrightarrows \mathsf{D}_{\text{qc}}(\mathcal{D}_Y):f^!.$$

If we restrict to the subcategory of complexes with *holonomic* cohomology, then the Verdier duality functor allows us to find left adjoints $f^*$ and $f_!$ of $f_*$ and $f^!$, respectively.

**I wonder if those adjoints already exist in $\mathsf{D}_{\text{qc}}(\mathcal{D}_X)$.**

Perhaps we can use Brown representability for left adjoints (as in Neeman's book about triangulated categories) or some other adjoint functor theorem...

In Neeman's paper *The Grothendieck Duality Theorem via Bousfield's Techniques*, it is proven that $f_*$ has a **right** adjoint (even though in the text it is said that it's a left adjoint). Perhaps we can use this functor to construct our left adjoints?

Comment: Here we see a difference between `\mathsf{}` and `\textsf{}`: $\mathsf{D}(\mathcal{D}_X\mathsf{-Mod})$ versus $\mathsf{D}(\mathcal{D}_X\textsf{-Mod}).$ The latter gives you a hyphen rather than a minus sign. A hyphen would be standard here, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Indeed, I usually have a macro for categories so I forgot how to do it right. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do not exist in general. The simplest example is maybe to take $X\rightarrow Y$ to be the closed embedding of the origin inside $\mathbb{A}^1.$ Then $f_*$ sends a vector space $V$ to the $\mathcal{D}_{\mathbb{A}^1}$-module $V\otimes\delta_0$, where $\delta_0$ is the irreducible $\mathcal{D}_{\mathbb{A}^1}$-module set-theoretically supported at $0$. The point is that because $\delta_0$ is infinite-dimensional as a vector space, this functor does not commute with products and hence cannot have a left adjoint.

Comment: this seems like the right direction but I'd think you need an example with nonholonomic D-modules, and not a closed embedding where you have Kashiwara's equivalence

Comment: @DavidBen-Zvi I don't think Kashiwara's is a problem - the category $D(\mathbb{A}^1)_0$ of D-modules supported at $0$ is not closed under limits, no? (I.e. it admits limits but they don't agree with the limits in $D(\mathbb{A}^1).$)

Comment: ah thanks, I guess the point is the inclusion of (ind)holonomics into all D modules doesn’t preserve limits, so the holonomic adjunction doesn’t help