# Can we use Mann's six-functor formalism with D-modules?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, infinity-categories, d-modules

[In a recent course in Bonn](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/scholze/SixFunctors.pdf), P. Scholze explains a formalization of a six-functor formalism due to L. Mann. In this axiomatization, three of the functors $f_!,f^*,\otimes$ are "constructed" (in the form of a lax monoidal functor) and then the other three are defined as right adjoints.

Now, in the derived category of holonomic D-modules over an algebraic variety in characteristic zero, we have four functors which are simple to construct:

1. $f_+$: the usual direct image of D-modules, which is the analog of the functor $f_*$;
2. $f^!$: the exceptional inverse image, which plays the same role as the homonymous functor in other six-functor formalisms;
3. $\otimes^\mathsf{L}_{\mathcal{O}}$: the left derived functor of the O-module tensor product;
4. $\mathrm{D}$: the "Verdier duality", which also works as in other six-functor formalisms.

Let me be precise: the functor $\otimes^\mathsf{L}_{\mathcal{O}}$ is **not** one of the six functors. (For example, in a six-functor formalism one would expect that the inverse image functor is monoidal with respect to the tensor product. This does not happen here.) But we can make it work!

Since $f^!$ is defined as a shift of $\mathsf{L}f^*$ (the O-module functor, which is also **not** one of the six-functors), and $\mathsf{L}f^*$ is monoidal with respect to $\otimes^\mathsf{L}_{\mathcal{O}}$, we can put $\otimes^!:=\otimes^\mathsf{L}_{\mathcal{O}}[-\dim]$. Then $f^!$ is monoidal with respect to $\otimes^!$. Finally, as the usual inverse image of D-modules $f^+$ is defined as the Verdier dual of $f^!$, we can define $\otimes$ as the Verdier dual of $\otimes^!$.

This tensor product $\otimes$ has a right adjoint $\underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(-,-)=\mathrm{D}(-\otimes\mathrm{D}(-))$ and the functors $f_+,f^!$ have left adjoints $f_!,f^+$; constituting a full six-functor formalism. (Which satisfies every nice property imaginable. And makes the analogy between holonomic D-modules and wildly ramified perverse sheaves in positive characteristic very clear.)

My question is: **how could we use (or modify) L. Mann's foundations to establish this six-functor formalism?** If we already know everything about this six-functor formalism, I guess it should not be too bad to prove that it enters in Mann's axiomatization. But those foundations should give simpler proofs to known (or not) statements; not repose on them, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The six functor formalism applies to $D$-modules, but you need to extend the theory to possibly non-smooth schemes. For this, we see that hypersheaves on the site of pairs $(X,Z)$, with $Z$ a closed subscheme of a smooth scheme $X$, with maps the obvious commutative squares, with coverings those maps $(X,Z)\to (X',Z')$ inducing an étale covering $Z\to Z'$ form an $\infty$-category equivalent to the $\infty$-category of hypersheaves on the usual big étale site of our ground field of characteristic zero (but we could work with arithmetic $D$-modules à la Berthelot for fields of positive characteristic, using the work of Caro). Sending $(X,Z)$ to $D$-modules over $X$ that are supported on $Z$, we get a hypersheaf of symmetric monioidal stable $\infty$-categories. What precedes says that there is a unique (hyper)sheaf of symmetric monoidal stable $\infty$-categories on the big étale that coincides with usual $D$-modules on smooth schemes (the proof is an interpretation of Kashiwara's theorem). This says how to define $\otimes$ and $f^*$ for any map of schemes of finite type over the ground field $f:Z\to Z'$. To define $f_!$, we reduce by descent as above to the case where $f$ is induced by a map of pairs $(X,Z)\to (X',Z')$, in which case we use the $g_!$ induced by $g:X\to X'$ restricted to $D$-modules supported on $Z$ and $Z'$ respectively.

Comment: I guess that one could also work with Grothendieck's infinitesimal site (in Dix Exposés), or de Rham stacks with solid coefficients.

Comment: @Z.M I do not think that your guess is correct: the infinitesimal site point of view leads the development of crystalline cohomology and the latter is not homotopy invariant. But the six operations imply cdh-descent, hence, using resolution of singularities, since de Rham cohomology is homotopy invariant for smooth schemes, any theory of six operations of $D$-modules defined on all schemes must lead to an homotopy invariant theory.

Comment: Dear @D.-C.Cisinski, if I understand correctly your construction, both the tensor product and the inverse image come from your hypersheaf of D-modules on $X$ supported on $Z$. I.e., we need to construct them as usual for smooth D-modules. (But those were the "hard" functors, that one would like to avoid constructing explicitly!) The same happens with your $g_!$.

Comment: All in all, I have the impression that you're doing what I said in the end: using all the knowledge of the six-functors for holonomic D-modules to construct it in this new formalism. (Of course, we get more out of it: we now have more compatibilities, everything works for singular schemes as well, etc...)

Comment: I was talking about things in char 0, thus it is homotopy invariant, I think.

Comment: The de Rham cohomology is not $\mathbb A^1$-invariant in char p, either: the de Rham cohomology of $\mathbb F_p[T]$ over $\mathbb F_p$ is very nontrivial.

Comment: @Z.M. That is why I said the ground field would be of characteristic zero. In positive characteristic I mentioned the possibility to work with Berthelot's Arithmetic D-modules. They correspond to rigid cohology wich coincides with crystalline cohomology for proper and smooth schemes, while being homotopy invariant.

Comment: @Gabriel To my knowledge it is always hard to construct all of the operators $f*$, $\otimes$ and $f_!$ (there is always at least one of them that causes trouble) and no formalism will do that for you. Formalism is a way to make precise the kind of functoriality and of coherence you should provide and/or expect.

Comment: @In particular I answered your question and I do not believe there is anything else to  say. The triviality of the answer fits with the depth of the question.

Comment: @D.-C.Cisinski I'm a bit confused by your answer. Most importantly, in Lucas Mann's construction principle, you don't have to construct $f_!$, you just check that it exists. Often the only nontrivial step is to check proper base change. I plan to write up some notes on $D$-modules for my course; I think one can give fairly direct proofs (not having to rely on hard theorems). Also, six functors as in Mann's definition don't have to satisfy excision, $\mathbb A^1$-invariance or cdh-descent, which is good as coherent sheaves don't.

Comment: (By the way, when referring to it as Mann's definition, I'm aware that closely related definitions have been around (Liu-Zheng, Gaitsgory-Rozenblyum, etc), but as far as I'm aware Mann was the first to pin down this precise definition, which at least for my concerns is the "best" among many closely related definitions.)

Comment: @Z.M Regarding your first comment: Yes, I think one could also set up this using the infinitesimal site (in characteristic 0), or the de Rham stack (which is essentially the same story), or also with solid modules (where one can treat formal completions differently, and accordingly gets a slightly different theory). I'm still a bit confused about the relations between all possible choices (I'm just learning about D-modules...), I hope to clear this up for myself while writing the notes...

Comment: @Scholze We should maybe define "hard" before discussing what it means to avoid "hard theorems". My answer above is not very precise about what should be proved about $f_!$ or not: I just wanted to emphazise that we should extend the theory to non smooth schemes. (to be continued)

Comment: @Scholze Since we want the theory to agree with the usual one for smooth schemes, if we do it the way I suggest above, we need Kashiwara's theorem (I am not sure what people call hard in there, but it seems to me that, simply to formulate the theorem, you need the "hard" part, and, once it is formulated, this is not "hard" to prove). I look forward to see how you will present the theory in your lectures, though!

Comment: @Scholze I am also a little bit confused by some of your comments: what is the difference between constructing $f_!$ and proving it exists? Even if you consider Mann's thesis as way to obtain $f_!$, then you must prove that the assumptions of his theorem hold, the proof of which will then be the "hard part" of the construction of $f_!$ (e.g. the proper base change in étale cohomology).

Comment: @D.-C.Cisinski just to clarify: Kashiwara's theorem is *not* what I meant by a "hard" theorem. Instead, it's "hard" to show that there's a natural transformation $f_!\to f_*$, which is an isomorphism for proper $f$, and it's "hard" to show that $f_*$ preserves the derived category of holonomic D-modules.

Comment: Dear @PeterScholze, as far as I know, there are no books or papers (except from Brad Drew's thesis and some papers of Martin Gallauer) which even consider the tensor product which I explained. (Which is, I think, absolutely necessary if we want to have a six-functor formalism satisfying the same formulas as usual.) Also there's not much on D-modules over singular schemes. So, the literature on D-modules would really benefit from you explaining this six-functor formalism. :)

Comment: @D.-C.Cisinski About "constructing $f_!$ vs proving that it exists": In the construction principle I explain in lecture 4 of my notes, the functor $f_!$ is not additional data; rather its existence is really a proposition (in the HTT sense, if you want). I agree that the verification of the assumptions becomes the hard part, but that part is not anymore a construction (i.e., you don't have to supply any data), it's just proving a theorem. And let's see how me writing the notes goes, but I think it won't really be hard either.

Comment: Re "hard: I wasn't able to give a slick presentation of the usual proper base change theorem in etale cohomology (a proof would seem to require a further digression), so I'd consider that "hard".

Comment: @Gabriel Then I am afraid I do not know how to avoid what you call hard theorems. We will need to understand $f_!=f_*$ at least in the case of closed immersions and of the projection of the form $\mathbb P^n \times X\to X$ and I do not know how to avoid that, whatever formalism we use for $D$-modules. The tensor product you consider is well known: this is the one obtained from the one of ordinary sheaves through the Rienmann-Hilbert correspondence, isnt'it?

Comment: @Scholze the fact that $f_!$ can be obtained uniquely by universal property is well known since Deligne's construction in the 60's then (the story of the subject is then to promote this gradually in more abstract/structured settings). We could compare all this story with Kan extensions. We want to extend some functorialities to a $2$-functor from a suitable $2$-category of correspondences. Abstract constructions are nice and can provide existence easily, but we want to compute the resulting extension in elementary terms. What we call "construction of $f_!$" is in fact this computation.

Comment: Dear @D.-C.Cisinski, it is indeed the tensor product corresponding to the analytic one via RH. I indeed expect the fact that "with this tensor product, the six-funtor formalism of holonomic D-modules satisfies precisely the same properties that the one of l-adic perverse sheaves over finite fields" to be known to experts. However, away from literally two papers by Martin Gallauer and Brad Drew's thesis, I never saw this anywhere. Do you know a single other paper which uses this tensor product?

Comment: @Gabriel You may have a look at Gaitsgory and Rozenblyum paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2087 Contrary to what I wrote earlier, we can everything with crystals: this follows from Prop. 2.5.6 and paragraph 5.5.2 in there. You may complete with chapter 4 in their book "A Study in Derived Algebraic Geometry" Vol. II (in which the tensor product you want is introduced). You may extract from there the answer you would have liked: use Mann's thesis instead of Part III "A Study in Derived Algebraic Geometry" Vol. II in order to get the six operations for D-modules.

Comment: As far as I understand, neither this paper nor this book says nothing about holonomic D-modules (and we *don’t* have the six-functors for more general D-modules). The beginning of chapter 4 in the aforementioned book even says that the pov of crystals seems to be ill suited for dealing with holonomicity. (I also didn’t found the tensor product that I’ve explained anywhere in there.)

Answer (score 12):

I have finally found some time to write up the $6$-functor formalisms in coherent cohomology (a la Gaitsgory--Rozenblyum) and for $D$-modules, see Lecture 8 and its appendix.

A short synopsis is that one can start with the functor taking any separated finite type $k$-scheme $X$ to its symmetric monoidal presentable stable $\infty$-category of crystals on the infinitesimal site, i.e.
$$
\mathrm{Crys}(X) = \mathrm{lim}_{R,\mathrm{Spec}(R_{\mathrm{red}})\to X} D(R)
$$
where $R$ runs over finite type $k$-algebras with a map from $\mathrm{Spec}(R_{\mathrm{red}})\to X$.

To construct a $6$-functor formalism, you need to specify in addition the class of morphisms $I$ for which $f_!$ should definitionally be a left adjoint of $f^\ast$, and the class of morphisms $P$ for which $f_!$ should definitionally be a right adjoint of $f^\ast$. Usually $I$ are the open immersions and $P$ the proper maps. Here, we do the opposite! I.e., $I$ are the proper maps, $P$ are the open immersions. The construction principle still works, yielding the desired $6$-functor formalisms, based on three functors $\otimes$, $f^\ast$ and $f_!$.

Now my notation is completely off with respect to the standard notation. This $6$-functor formalism $X\mapsto \mathrm{Crys}(X)$ with $\otimes,f^\ast,f_!$ is isomorphic to Gaitsgory--Rozenblyum's $X\mapsto \mathrm{IndCoh}(X_{\mathrm{dR}})$ with their $\otimes^!,f^!,f_\ast$. And this is isomorphic to the other $6$-functor formalisms on big categories of $D$-modules, with similarly sounding functors.

As I discuss in the notes, things are slightly less confusing if you work with opposite categories, i.e. with
$$
\mathrm{Crys}(X)^{\mathrm{op}} = \mathrm{lim}_{R,\mathrm{Spec}(R_{\mathrm{red}})\to X} D(R)^{\mathrm{op}}
$$
where $D(R)^{\mathrm{op}}=\mathrm{Pro}(\mathrm{Perf}(R))$ (using naive duality on $\mathrm{Perf}(R)$). Also, as $\mathrm{Crys}(X)$ is compactly generated with compact objects the coherent $D$-modules, and the compact objects admit a selfduality (basically, Verdier duality), one has a canonical identification
$$
\mathrm{Crys}(X)^{\mathrm{op}} = \mathrm{Pro}(\mathrm{Crys}(X)^\omega).
$$

The functors $\otimes,f^\ast,f_!$ of course induce similar functors on opposite categories, and when you restrict to the compact objects, you get the usual functors on $\mathrm{Crys}(X)^\omega$ i.e. coherent $D$-modules.

As you can see in the notes, I think the formalism really helps in the construction (or at least I found it helpful...), everything can be done by hand. In particular, Gaitsgory--Rozenblyum's $\mathrm{IndCoh}$ formalism can be defined without difficult properties of the Gray tensor product of $(\infty,2)$-categories, in fact without any $(\infty,2)$-categories at all.

Final comment: I am using here as pullback what is usually called "naive" pullback; the "true" pullback is usually a shift of the naive pullback. I think this shift shouldn't actually be introduced, and ultimately results from a "wrong" identification of left and right $D$-modules -- one should identify them by tensoring with $\omega_X = \Omega^d_X[d]$, but often one simply uses $\Omega^d_X$ (where things are defined on the abelian level).

Comment: Isn’t it also possible to define a sheaf theory a la Gaitsgory-Rozenblyum which sends an affine scheme to its (Ind) category of holonomic D-modules? Unfortunately I don’t know how to define the latter on singular schemes without using embeddings into smooth schemes

Comment: A very minor point: Remark 8.40 has a broken citation.

Comment: Dear @PeterScholze, I admit that I don't really understand what you did in there. The "hard theorems" that I said before all deal with problems of holonomicity, which you seem to avoid entirely. Actually, I was basically convinced that there was *no* six-functor formalism for quasi-coherent D-modules (I even thought that condensed mathematics could perhaps help here...). For example, as far as I understand, GR only deal with a 3-functor formalism.

How does you formalism avoid this problem in here? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405511/six-functor-formalism-for-quasi-coherent-d-modules

Comment: Also, on left D-modules, the "true" pullback $f^!$ has to be a shift of the "naive" one if we want it to be adjoint to $f_!$, I think... (Of course, you could shift $f_*$ then... but I'm not sure if that's what you want. For example, if $M$ is a holonomic D-module and $p:X\to \operatorname{pt}$ is the structure map, then $p_* M$ and $p_! M$ only have cohomologies in degrees from $-\dim X$ up to $\dim X$. This is very similar to what happens with perverse sheaves, and I guess we would like to keep it.)

Comment: @Gabriel As I say towards the end, if you take the $\mathrm{Pro}$-perspective (and restrict to coherent $D$-modules), you get the standard $\otimes,f^\ast,f_!$ functors. You can then further restrict to holonomic $D$-modules, and then some hard theorems tell you that this category is stable under all six operations. But for the construction of the functors, you don't need the theorems.

Comment: The problem from the cited question disappears because I've renamed $f^!$ and $f_\ast$ into $f^\ast$ and $f_!$, and their right adjoint do exist (as well as internal Hom), so you get a 6-functor formalism. (It doesn't "feel" like one, but we have a definition, and it fits the bill!) It's just that the functors don't quite mean what you'd think they mean. But they do once you pass to opposite categories. (But then it's just a 3-functor formalism as the required right adjoints cease to exist; also, your categories are no longer presentable.)